# How to wrap and 'objectize' functions and time in setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, oop, settimeout

for example, if I need to do task s1,s2,s3 linerly,it would be look like this:

```js
var s1=function(){
  document.write("[1s task]");
  setTimeout(s2,2000);
}
var s2=function(){
  document.write("[2s task]");
  setTimeout(s3,3000);
}
var s3=function(){
  document.write("[3s task]");
}
setTimeout(s1,1000);
```

but it is very hard to maintain if I want to change the order from s1,s2,s3 to s3,s1,s2. How to wrap and 'objectize' a task which look like this:

```
mySetTimeout(new MyTask(s1,1000),new MyTask(s2,1000),new MyTask(s3,1000));
```

so that it is easy to change order from s1,s2,s3 to s3,s1,s2:

```
mySetTimeout(new MyTask(s3,3000),new MyTask(s1,1000),new MyTask(s2,2000));
```

? How to write mySetTimeout and MyTask?

Comment: This would be an interesting question, if you only would have tried something ...

Comment: No need to objectise everything. Just use callbacks. Or with promises, it could look like `s1().then(s2).then(s3)`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you didn't know you were looking for are promises. They're objects representing asynchronous results, and can be chained with callback functions.

```js
function delay(t) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, t);
    });
}

function s1() {
    console.log("[1s task]");
    return delay(1000);
}
function s2() {
    console.log("[2s task]");
    return delay(2000);
}
function s3() {
    console.log("[3s task]");
    return delay(3000);
}

s1().then(s2).then(s3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a schedule task which takes different tasks as parameters (an example below)

```
function scheduleTask()
{
   var args = [...arguments];
   var firstTask = args.slice(0,1)[0];
   args = args.slice(1);
   //console.log(args, firstTask);
   firstTask && setTimeout( function(){ 
        firstTask( function(){
          scheduleTask(...args);
       });
   }, 1000); //timeout is constant
}
scheduleTask(s1, s2, s3);
```

**Demo**

```js
function scheduleTask()
{
   var args = [...arguments];
   var firstTask = args.slice(0,1)[0];
   args = args.slice(1);
   //console.log(args, firstTask);
   firstTask && setTimeout( function(){ 
        firstTask( function(){
          scheduleTask(...args);
       });
   }, 1000); //timeout is constant
}
scheduleTask(s1, s2, s3);

function s1( cb )
{
   console.log("s1");
   cb();
}

function s2( cb )
{
   console.log("s2");
   cb();
}

function s3( cb )
{
   console.log("s3");
   cb();
}
```

Or as suggested by @Thomas you can shorten it by doing

```
function scheduleTask(firstTask, ...args) 
{
  firstTask && setTimeout(function() {
    firstTask(function() {
      scheduleTask(...args);
    });
  }, 1000); //timeout is constant
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function scheduleTask(firstTask, ...args) 
{
  firstTask && setTimeout(function() {
    firstTask(function() {
      scheduleTask(...args);
    });
  }, 1000); //timeout is constant
}
scheduleTask(s1, s2, s3);

function s1(cb) {
  console.log("s1");
  cb();
}

function s2(cb) {
  console.log("s2");
  cb();
}

function s3(cb) {
  console.log("s3");
  cb();
}
```

Comment: why don't you do? `function scheduleTask(firstTask, ...args)` why so complicated?

Comment: @Thomas can you share what is so complicated about it?

Comment: @Thomas But its a good idea, though. I have added it to the answer.

Comment: *"what is so complicated about it?"* You use the spread operator, so it's not about backwards compatibility; yet you don't use it to its full capabilities. It feels **unnecessarily** detailed/intricate, or complicated, to implement that on your own. And the code I've added is better at communicating what you're doing, in my opinion. Or maybe I just didn't get your thoughts/reasons, that's why I commented on your answer

Answer (score 0):

I guess @Bergi's promise way is nice but you may still sequence your jobs without using promises. Just put your jobs in an array in the order you like them get processed and use a recursive sequencer.

```js
var seqJobs = ([j,...js]) => j && setTimeout(_ => (j.job(), seqJobs(js)), j.dly),
    jobs    = [{job: _ => console.log("[0s task]"), dly: 500},
               {job: _ => console.log("[1s task]"), dly: 2000},
               {job: _ => console.log("[2s task]"), dly: 3000},
               {job: _ => console.log("[3s task]"), dly: 1000}];

seqJobs(jobs);
```